# Controle de versão antes de 1990

Tags: git, versionamento

Estou estudando sobre controle de versões através do livro *Controlando Versões com Git e Github* (Casa do Código).

No começo do livro os autores dizem que pré-git, em meados dos anos 90, já existiam ferramentas de versionamento.

Aí me surgiu uma dúvida: como era feito o controle de versão antes dos anos 90?

Comment: Um muito usado era o DPL/DPC (disquete pra lá / disquete pra cá) :-) Brincadeiras à parte (mas nem tanto, muita gente de fato fazia isso), aqui tem algumas referências: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/310163 - destaque para a imagem que mostra uma timeline: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBZd0.png

Comment: GIT é uma ferramenta comum, muito bem feita, mas está longe de ser a única. Acho que a pergunta parte de  uma premissa errada, como se  o GIT fosse divisor de águas. Não só não é, como demorou para pegar tração. Para projetos com time centralizado ou pequeno, nem é o mais prático nem o mais intuitivo. Eu diria que o GIT é o "martelo" do versionamento, o problema é que o pessoal além de usar em prego, tambem usa em parafuso, limpeza de vidraças, unha encravada, etc.

Comment: Só para esclarecer o fechamento: apesar do título diferente, tem resposta com a parte histórica, inclusive mencionando décadas antes da data da pergunta. As duplicatas são orientadas pela solução, e não pelo título original. Caso o link não resolva a dúvida, você pode [edit] o post e deixar mais evidentes as partes que não foram cobertas pela vinculação. A resposta a que me refiro é a que começa com _Um pouco de história_ / _Primórdios_ / _Os sistemas de controle de versão são bem antigos. Alguns dos primeiros conhecidos foram o CA Software Change Manager, o Panvalet e o SCCS em 1972._ ...